# Calculus - application of the intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function, $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$.

For which values of a$ \in \mathbb{R}$ does there necessarily exist $c \in [0,1]$ such that $f(c) = ac$?

Is the following answer sufficient?

if $f(0) = 0$

for any value of $a \in \mathbb{R}$

if $f(0) > 0$:

for all values $a>f(1)$:

we define $g(x) = f(c)-ac$

since $f(0) > 0, g(0) > 0$

since $a > f(1), g(1) = f(1) - a < 0$

by the Intermediate Value Theorem we get that there must be a value $y$ such that $g(y) = 0 \implies f(c) = ac$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Thanks.

Comment: So far, so good, but what if $a \le f(1)$?

Comment: Then there might not be a solution: intuitively, we only need ac to cross f(c), it might not if f(c) = 1 and a ≤ f(1)